# sed command to remove curly braces around specific string

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, sed

I am trying to remove only the curly braces that are around string "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
Can anyone please help with this ? Thank you !

Input:

```
        {
            "FromPort": 1024,
            "ToPort": 65535,
            "IpProtocol": "udp",
                {
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                },
                {
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Output:

```
        {
            "FromPort": 1024,
            "ToPort": 65535,
            "IpProtocol": "udp",
            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure? The input looks like an invalid JSON (missing opening `[`), and the output is even worse, as it makes no sense to have a repeated key in a JSON.

Comment: This is just an snippet with dummy values.

Comment: Even if using sed were a good idea (see John Hanley's answer), getting the indentation right would be a pain. (If you wanted to take a chance and didn't care about the indentation, you could use `sed '/{$/{N;N;s| *{\n\( *"CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"\)\n *}|\1|;}'` at your own risk.)

Answer (score 1):

SED does not understand JSON. SED is a line oriented editor / parser. JSON can be written all on one line, multiline, etc. No matter what pattern you created for JSON, it would not be consistent or reliable.

Use JQ to parse JSON. Then you can use tools such as sed, cut, etc. on the JQ output.

[JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Answer (score 0):

If the whitespace is repeatable, if the input is limited, if you know this is a hack versus the right way to handle structured data, etc:

`sed '/{/{N;/Cidr/{N;s/[^\n]*\n//;s/\n.*//;s/        //;}}' input-file`

- `/{/` for lines matching open curly

  - `N` add the next line to the pattern space
  - `/Cidr/` for pattern spaces matching "Cidr"

    - `N` get the next line
    - `s/[^\n]*\n//` delete the first line
    - `s/\n.*//` delete the last line
    - `s/        //` delete some whitespace to de-indent the "Cidr" data

The last whitespace deletion may need to be modified if the true input data is using tabs.  My quick testcase ended up with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -r -z "s,{([^{}]*CidrIp[^{}]*)},\1,g" input-file
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xy8DQ1/1)

-i : in-place (output file same as input)

-r : extended regex

-z : treat file as one string, instead of default line-by-line

This may leave some extra new-lines, but they are are easy to replace with additional replacement command.